# username check with Ajax fails

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using Codeigniter 4 and ajax to check if an username exists. It fails.

Here is the code that I used to check the username.
I wanted a popup  to show (*available* or *not available*) below the input box when the user is typing a username

AJAX

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#unameAkun").keyup(function() {
                var username = $(this).val().trim();
                if (username != '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo base_url('Dashboard_db/cek_username') ?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            username: username
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#username_result').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#username_result").html("");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

MODEL

```
public function cek_username($email_akun){
    return $this->db->table('tabel_akun')->where(array('email_akun'=>$email_akun))->get()->getRowArray();}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function cek_username() {
    if (isset($_POST['unameAkun'])) {
        $username = $_POST['unameAkun'];
        $results = $this->Akun_->cek_username($username);
        if ($results>0) {
            $response = "<span style='color: red;'>Not Available.</span>";
        } else {
            $response = "<span style='color: green;'>Available.</span>";
        }
    }
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: to get an answer to this question, you need to explain what your controller function cek_username() looks like (and eventually the corresponding model)

Comment: the controller : https://i.postimg.cc/MGxHRmx0/image.png

Comment: the model : https://i.postimg.cc/XYK7VBFr/image.png

Comment: no code in image please, 
Please do not use screenshots of your code and error messages and **do not link to external sources like pastebin**. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot 

be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: Ok sorry then
This is the pastebin link : https://pastebin.com/mCC6ygnK

Comment: I think you want to use `countAllResults()`instead of `getRowArray`

Comment: ok, thats working. But when I type the exist username, it always popup "available"

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where does that code go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now you are querying for email instead of username, change your model to something like:

```
public function cek_username($username){
    return $this->db ->table('tabel_akun')
                     ->where(array('unameAkun'=>$username))
                     ->get()
                     ->countAllResults;
}
```

as you see, I've also changed getRowArray() into countAllResults(), as you want to return how often the username exists.

Further, I would use in the javascript part `change` instead `keyup`, so it only checks, once you have the full username (the event is deferred until the element loses focus) and not for each letter, but that's optional, as you like.